# passing variables outside of functions in jquery

Tags: jquery, function, global-variables

I was wondering if it is possible to pass variables outside of a function?

```
$('.selector').hover(function(){
var variable = $('.selector2', this).attr('id');
});
```

I need to get that variable to use it outside of this hover function. Is it possible?

Thanks!

EDIT ------------------------

I'm trying to click something else getting that variable outside of the hover function

```
$('a.btn').click(function(){
alert(variable);
});
```

Comment: The best way to get it outside the hover function depends upon what you want to do.  The most straightforward way would be to just pass it as a parameter and call a function from within the hover call.  But, whether that's the right answer here depends upon what else you want to do and when you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to first declare that variable in a higher scope:

```
var variable;

$('.selector').hover(function(){
    variable = $('.selector2', this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: This gives me undefined value? I edited my post to see what I'm trying to do outside my hover function.

Comment: @andrewliu: This'll give you *undefined* if you click your `a.btn` before you hover over `.selector`. If you do not fully understand why, refer to @asawyer's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Like in the next line of code after this?  You  have a serious misunderstanding of how this whole jQuery thing works if that is the case my friend.

You are declaring what amounts to a callback function not actually running any code. The function defined here will be invoked at some point in the future, outside of your control.*

Another problem you have here is that you have a selector here that can contain multiple dom elements, 0 to x number of them.

If you need to get a list of all Id's from a selector that's easily done, look at [.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) or something similar, just be aware you are dealing with a set of controls not a single, even if your only selecting one item.

**Unless you invoke the event yourself*

Comment: sorry. I'm having a little difficulty understanding. I'm really new to jquery and I'm still learning. Do you think you can show an example? I learn better that way? Thank you!

Comment: @andrewliu It would help if you could explain exactly what your trying to do here.

Comment: when I hover over the element. I can click on a link for that specific id. (lets say if I wanted to delete it). I can click on the link to delete that specific element, but a pop up notification will ask to make sure to remove or cancel. If I click on the remove, it will remove that element. I'm trying to capture the id outside of hover so when theres a pop up, my mouse can move away from that element with the hover so I can click remove. Does this make sense? I did do another way, where I just put a click function inside the hover which works, but I'd like to know if this is possible as well.

Comment: Honestly, I would create a new question like that, that explicatively lays out exactly what your trying to do, what you have now, and the problems your running. You'll have much better luck then here in these comments.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to instantiate the variable you want before the hover handler.  Here is your updated code:

```
var variable = '';
$('.selector').hover(function(){
    variable = $('.selector2', this).attr('id');
});
alert(variable);  // alerts empty string because you haven't hovered over '.selector' yet
```

The problem is that you are likely trying to access variable before you set it, since it only gets set when a hover occurs